# Stationarity condition for unit ball

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Derivation of the necessary and sufficient stationarity conditions over the unit ball.

For $x$ in the unit ball, $x$ is a minimum point if $\nabla f(x) = 0$ or $||x|| = 1$ and $\exists l \leq 0$ s.t $\nabla f(x) = l*x$

Of course the first part makes sense however I don't understand how the second part of this is derived. I can see that using the definition of convexity it is obvious that $||x|| = 1$ however I'm not sure how to get the second part of the result.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\eqdef{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
As given, the statement is not true. The given conditions are not generally *sufficient* for $\ x\ $ to be a minimum of $\ f\ $ (although they *are* sufficient if you restrict $\ f\ $ to be *convex*). They are *necessary* however. Here's a proof for the case when the minimum $\ x\ $ lies on the surface of the unit ball.

If $\ x\ $ is a minimum of $\ f\ $ over the unit ball, and $\ \|x\|=1\ $, let $\ u\ $ be any unit vector perpendicular to  $\ x\ $ and define
$$
g(t)\eqdef f(\cos(t)x+\sin(t)u)
$$
Then since $\ \|\cos(t)x+\sin(t)u\|=1\ $ for all $\ t\ $ we must have
\begin{align}
g(t)&=f(\cos(t)x+\sin(t)u)\\
&\ge f(x)\\
&=g(0)\ .
\end{align}
Thus $\ g(t)\ $ is at a minimum when $\ t=0\ $.  Therefore
\begin{align}
0&=g'(0)\\
&=\langle \nabla f(x),u\rangle
\end{align}
Since this holds for all unit vectors perpendicular to $\ x\ $ it follows that
\begin{align}
\nabla f(x)&\in(\{u\}^\perp)^\perp\\
&=\{\,\lambda x\,|\,\lambda\in\Bbb{R}\,\}\ ,
\end{align}
or, in other words, $\ \nabla f(x)=\lambda x\ $ for some $\ \lambda\in\Bbb{R}\ $. Now define
$$
h(t)\eqdef f(tx)\ .
$$
Then for all $\ t\in[-1,1]\ $, $\ tx\ $ is in the unit ball, and therefore
\begin{align}
h(t)&=f(tx)\\
&\ge f(x)\\
&=h(1)\ .
\end{align}
Thus $\ h(t)\ $ is at a minimum over the interval $\ [-1,1]\ $ when $\ t=1\ $. Therefore
\begin{align}
0&\ge h'(1)\\
&=\langle \nabla f(x),x\rangle\\
&=\lambda\langle x,x\rangle\\
&=\lambda
\end{align}
which completes the proof that $\ \nabla f(x)=\lambda x\ $ for some $\ \lambda\le0\ $.